# Django validator not preventing invalid IPv4 address from being added to database

Tags: django

I am experimenting with Django's validate_ipv46_address validator in my model:

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    ... omitted for brevity ...
    allowed_network_ips = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=225, null=True, validators=[validate_ipv4_address]))
    ...
```

I have a view with a POST method that creates a `Policy` object which looks like:

```
class PolicyView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, namespace_id):
        ...
        allowed_network_ips = request.data.get('allowed_network_ips')
        ...
        try:
            np = Policy.objects.create( 
                          ...                                       
                          allowed_network_ips=allowed_network_ips,
                          ...
            )
            serialized_np = PolicySerializer(np, many=False)

        except Exception as ex:
            ...            
            return Response({"message": message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 

        return Response(serialized_np.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I am testing this with this curl script that has an invalid ipv4 address.
The curl script looks like this:

```
curl -v -X POST \
"http://example.com/namespace/49/policy" \
...
-d '{ "..., "allowed_network_ips": ["not.an.ipv4.addres"], ... }'
```

I was hoping I would get some sort of error because I do not think `not.an.ipv4.addres` is a valid ipv4 address (I could be wrong there), but 
the POST works and a `Policy` with `allowed_network_ips` of `not.an.ipv4.addres` gets created.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run), validation only occurs when using `ModelForms`. Since you are directly creating your object from the request data, you should create an instance of that object, and then call `full_clean` method on that object:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class PolicyView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, namespace_id):
        ...
        allowed_network_ips = request.data.get('allowed_network_ips')
        ...
        try:
            instance = Policy( 
                          ...                                       
                          allowed_network_ips=allowed_network_ips,
                          ...
            )

            try:
                instance.full_clean()
            except ValidationError:
                  # Handle the error
            else:
                instance.save()

            serialized_np = PolicySerializer(instance, many=False)

        except Exception as ex:
            ...            
            return Response({"message": message}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 

        return Response(serialized_np.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

The validators are skipped because `.create()` doesn't call [`.full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean).

Just add `np.full_clean()` right after you create it.

Comment: if `np.full_clean()` catches an invalid IP would it remove the created `Policy` record or would I have to delete it with something like `if not np.full_clean(): np.delete()` ?

Comment: Correct, `full_clean()` will not delete it. You could also just do `np = Policy(...)` then clean and only save if there are no validation errors.